# PHP Notice: Undeifined variable when call API to a PHP page

Tags: php, mysql

currently I create a system that has add function. Before add,  a function needs to check either the data already exists in the database or not.

This two function requires to call two API. Now, when i run the code, I got this error:

PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: Fac_ID in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ebooking\api\api_add_factory.php on line 5

and below is my current code:

add_factory.php

```
<?php

    include("../../config/check.php");
    include("../../api/api_add_factory.php"); //include web services

    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
    {

      $Fac_ID = $_POST['Fac_ID'];

      $queryt = callApi1();

      if(empty($queryt)){

              $json2 = callApi2();

              if(!empty($json2)){

                header("Location:factory.php");

              }else{
                echo "
                <script>alert('Something wrong, please try again')</script>
                <script>window.location = 'factory.php'</script>
                ";

              }
            }
      else{

          echo "
          <script>alert('The factory you want to add is already exist')</script>
          <script>window.location = 'factory.php'</script>
          ";

      }
    }

?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <table width="90%">
      <tr>
        <td width="20%"><b>Factory Name</b></td>
        <td width="50%"><input type="text" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" class="form-control" name="Fac_ID" required></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to add this factory?');">
</form>
```

api_add_factory.php

```
<?php

    function callApi1(){

        $url = "http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/selectFactory?Fac_ID=$Fac_ID"; //line 5
        $data = file_get_contents($url);
        return json_decode($data);
    }

    function callApi2(){

        $url2 = "http://172.20.0.45/TGWebService/TGWebService.asmx/insertFactory?fac_id=$Fac_ID&fac_name=$Fac_ID";
        $data2 = file_get_contents($url2);
        return json_decode($data2);
    }

?>
```

Can anyone know what is the problem? How to fix it? Thanks

Comment: @showdev, then, where should I put api_add_factory?

Comment: I might pass the `$Fac_ID` value to the function, like `callApi1($Fac_ID)`. And then include that variable in the function's argument list, like `function callApi1($Fac_ID){...` Also see [Variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: @showdev only for callApi1? I already do, but I get This error "The factory you want to add is already exist"

Comment: @showdev can you help me to edit the code above?

Comment: Are you submitting a `<form>`? It might help to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60482034/edit) to include that relevant HTML and show how you currently pass variables to the functions.

Comment: @showdev yes. And I already edit the question. Please check

Comment: Assuming the form submits correctly and `$Fac_ID` gets defined, pass that variable to the functions: `$queryt = callApi1($Fac_ID);` and `$json2 = callApi2($Fac_ID);`. Make sure you set the functions' argument lists: `function callApi1($Fac_ID){` and `function callApi2($Fac_ID){`. Without passing the variable, it will not be in the [local function scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) and will be an "Undefined variable".

Comment: @showdev, already do, back it will popup error "The factory you want to add is already exist", although the factory that I add does not exist in the database

Comment: Your code shows `callApi1()`, which does not pass the variable. If you are passing the variable and getting that message, then the returned `$queryt` must not be empty. To troubleshoot, you might try outputting `$queryt` and see what it contains.

Comment: @showdev, sorry again, can I know how to do that? Sorry, I'm too new in programming.

Comment: I recommend `echo "<pre>".print_r($queryt,true)."</pre>";` or `var_dump($queryt);`.

Comment: @showdev, Thaks dude!! already solved!

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare variable $Fac_ID before the if condition.

Add the following line before the if condition.

```
$Fac_ID = null;
```

Or disable the PHP Notices.